# Why does packet data don't need trailer/footer while frame needs it?

Tags: networking, layers, frame

Why does packet don't need trailer/footer while frame needs it?

I am trying to understand networking concept regarding ISO & TCP/IP layering. I have googled a bit and it says that the footer in data link layer pdu (frame) is needed as a mark of the end of the pdu.

But why does packet data etc in the layers above it doesn't need footer to mark the end of the pdu as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the end is marked in the data link layer, there is no need to mark the end in higher layers. Higher layers usually don't need to replicate services provided by lower layers. Some layer has to mark the end of the data, and the data link layer is the one that does this.